# Run VirtualBox on Snow Leopard set to 64-bit?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, virtualbox, vmware-fusion

I know there are [problems](http://blogs.vmware.com/teamfusion/2009/08/vmware-fusion-2-and-max-os-x-snow-leopard-even-better.html) running VMWare Fusion when Snow Leopard has been set to boot as 64-bit. It will only run on 32-bit for now (default for desktop/laptop Macs).

Any news on whether Virtual Box can run on a 64-bit Snow Leopard host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VirtualBox 3.04 will run on SL64 - it has 64-bit kexts installed by default.

It's not without bugs though - the most severe I have faced is the occasional crash while accessing the Settings panel for a VM. Not exactly a big issue, just try to avoid touching the Settings panel while the VM is running. Other than that, I'm quite happy with its performance and functionality.

VMWare Fusion and Parallels as of now does not work with SL64.

Comment: Thanks for that. Your comments and reading http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=21757 makes me think I'll stay away until it becomes more stable.

Answer (score 2):

Just found this [compatibility list](http://snowleopard.wikidot.com/). VMWare Fusion, VirtualBox and Parallels only run on a 32-bit kernel Snow Leopard for now.

Answer (score 1):

from build 3846 it should work with parallels 4.0

It seems only VirtualBox 3.0.6 Beta has SL64 support see
[virtualbox forum](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=21757&start=15#p96409)

Vmware is late at the SL64 party :-(